# why return type Observable is better than primitive type?

Tags: angular, observable

I just started to implement the application in Angular 2. I have some questions about codes below. Why return Observable instead of just boolean type in that authenticate method? If I look around the source codes from experts, they return most of them as Observable. I am afraid that this might be stupid question, but I am curious about it.

```
authenticate(user: string, pass: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.request(new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.baseUrl + "login",
            body: { name: user, password: pass }
        })).map(response => {
            let r = response.json();
            this.auth_token = r.success ? r.token : null;
            return r.success;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that in almost all methods with an http request, they return observables.

That is because Http requests (network) request are inherently asynchronous. Meaning, when you make a network request, you dont know when in the call stack you should handle the response. The response is dependent on network speed, api efficiency, interference, etc..

Why Observables? They are subscribed to! You subscribe to them when the response comes through. Rxjs comes with a whole bunch of operators that make the parsing of responses, or there errors, a cleaner and more pleasant experience.

I recommend going through some Rxjs examples found online. Observables are super powerful. They can manage the state of your app, the data access layer, the view, and everything in between.

Check the rxjs site for documentation and visuals on everything rx. http://reactivex.io/

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/eRaCT7AqNNPIHpD3sCG0/ . This has rxjs imported so you can do any rxjs practice you want in the script.js page. Or a more Angular friendly typescript version: http://embed.plnkr.co/OdggjhnwjQLSwhYAjg8H

Answer (score 0):

The http request called inside functions are asynchronous which mean that the response may take a while to acheive to the client. Observables give you the privilege to wait the response and execute something.

For Example: Let's say you will return in this cas the boolean directly, you will always get null value because the function the http request doesn't wait the response to return it.

Comment: Really? but I have ever implemented to return boolean type in my very old test. It worked fine not returning null value...

Comment: While executing your program, If the response comes before the return line then you will have a boolean. It depends on the speed of your network maybe in the local dev environement you will not notice the problem. If you think this is not very clear you can share your code to clarify more. This is some [Observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Saying it's an observable lets it sort of say 'eventually we'll have this type of value coming back'. It allows for a stream of values to pass through over time which is why it's preferred to be used for every async http request. The map function also returns an observable, so trying to return a straight up Boolean would take some unnecessary work. Map(...) is preferred over .promise().then(...)